# Mask numpy array evaluating nan as True

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, masking

Consider a `numpy` array with the data:

```
aa = np.array([-4.793, -1.299, 0.453, np.nan, np.nan, 1.131, 0.684,  1.037])
```

I need to create a mask like so:

```
mask = -4. < aa
```

which evaluates to

```
array([False, True, True, False, False, True, True, True], dtype=bool)
```

Here's the catch: I need the `nan` values to evaluate to `True`.

I'm after a *general* solution that does not involve modifying my input array `aa`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite simple with a [logic function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html#numpy.logical_or)

```
import numpy as np

aa = np.array([-4.793, -1.299, 0.453, np.nan, np.nan, 1.131, 0.684,  1.037])

mask = np.logical_or(-4 < aa, np.isnan(aa))

print mask
# [False  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
```